# Recover deleted files Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, file-recovery

Yes, I know I should've had a backup, but I accidentally rm -rf'ed a folder with some files I need in it.

It was in the home directory, I shutdown the Pi as soon as I realised.

Is there some file recovery software I can use or something?

Comment: see if this helps: http://www.linux.org/threads/undelete-files-on-linux-systems.4316/

Comment: Also the Arch Linux Wiki,as always, has an excellent page onfile recovery: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_recovery